# NullPointerException while calling getter JFileChooser

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, getter, jfilechooser

I'm getting a NullPointerException every time I call a getter. Here's the code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileChooser extends JFileChooser {
private int result;
private File filename;
private File subFile;
private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;

    public FileChooser() {
        filename = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Subtitle Files (*.srt)", "srt");
    }

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        this.setDialogTitle("Select a file");
        this.setCurrentDirectory(filename);       
        this.setFileFilter(filter);
        result = this.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            subFile = this.getSelectedFile();   
        this.setVisible(true);        
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return subFile;
    }

}
```

I get null pointer everywhere I use the variable that calls the `getFile()` function. `foo` in this case. Here's the snippet:

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
File foo = fileChooser.getFile();
System.out.println(foo.getName()); //Null-Pointer
System.out.println(foo.getPath()); //Null-Pointer
```

**UPDATE:** I happen to have two instances of `FileChooser` but, I would like to call `createAndShowGUI()` only once. How do I initialise the selected file in the constructor ?

Comment: You should probably initialize subFile in the constructor also.

Comment: @wazaaaap How do I do that ?

Comment: Just cut the code in "createAndShowGUI" and paste it in the constructor. Now you don't need to call the function and it should work ok.

Comment: Pass it as an argument to the constructor and initialize it. (for the update)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

public class FileChooser extends JFileChooser {
    private int result;
    private File filename;
    private File subFile;
    private FileNameExtensionFilter filter;

    public FileChooser() {
        filename = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
        filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Subtitle Files (*.srt)", "srt");
        this.setDialogTitle("Select a file");
        this.setCurrentDirectory(filename);       
        this.setFileFilter(filter);
        result = this.showOpenDialog(this);
        if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
            subFile = this.getSelectedFile();   
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public File getFile() {
        return subFile;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well you are never calling `createAndShowGUI()`. Just call that before you call `getFile()`

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, the field `subFile` is initialized in the method `createAndShowGUI()` inside the `if condition`.

But, as you are not calling the method `createAndShowGUI()` the field `subFile` remains `null` when you call `getFile()`.

Try this code,

```
FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
fileChooser.createAndShowGUI();             // MISSING IN ORIGINAL CODE
File foo = fileChooser.getFile();
System.out.println(foo.getName()); //Null-Pointer
System.out.println(foo.getPath()); //Null-Pointer
```

**UPDATE**

As the question is updated with

> I happen to have two instances of FileChooser but, I would like to call createAndShowGUI() only once

If you call `createAndShowGUI()` only once then the user will be able to select the file only once.

Then what is the use of creating two instances of `FileChooser`?

You need to call `createAndShowGUI()` every time you create a new instance of `FileChooser`.

Comment: I call it in the main function before calling `getFile()`

Comment: You need to call `createAndShowGUI()` after you make an instance of `FileChooser`.

Comment: I added a code snippet to my answer. That should solve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is problem:

```
if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        subFile = this.getSelectedFile();
```

`result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION` return false and `subFile` never initialized